# How can I select specific parts of an image in android?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, android-library

If you have used photoshop, they have a tool that allows you to select parts of an image in order to edit specific locations within an image. Such as having a picture of a basketball and selecting that basketball with the use of the lasso tool in photoshop so you can make the rest of the image black and white.

I was wondering if there is any pre-defined class in the Android resource library that can make this sort of selection. Or would i have to make my own class that would look for a pattern in an image? Basically is there a tool available in android that can make these image selections that I can use inside my app?

It would also be helpful if someone can point me towards a reading on the subject of image selection programming or a third party library. I can't seem to find anything specific.

Comment: there's nothing that high-level in the SDK. it's possible there exists a third-party lib to do something like that, but i am not aware if any.